# ExtJs4 Model with different poxy url's

Tags: extjs4

I have defined a model which I want to use twice but with a different url int he proxy (in fact only the id differs) But how can I manage this?

```
Ext.define('TesterModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
autoLoad: false,
fields: [
    { name: 'prename', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'lastname', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'dept', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'rackName', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'rackIP' , vtype:'IPAddress'}],
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'php/getData_db.php?id=',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        messageProperty: 'message',
        root: 'data',
    }
},
constructor: function() {
    UrlParams=document.URL.split("?");
    if(UrlParams.length > 1) {
        SingleUrlParams=Ext.Object.fromQueryString(UrlParams[1]);
        this.proxy.url = this.proxy.url + SingleUrlParams.right;
        console.log(this.proxy.url);
        }
    return this;
}});


Ext.ModelMgr.getModel('TesterModel').load(0, { // load user with ID of "0"
success: function(tester) {
    var rightPanel=Ext.getCmp('rightTester');
    rightPanel.loadRecord(tester); // when tester is loaded successfully, load the data into the form
}
```

});

I thought that the constructor will be done before loading, but nope, it is done after. It's weired to me.
Any hints, please?

(the main URL it's like: .../index.html?left=xx&right=yy )
so I want to fill up a panel on the left with the one id, and a panel on the right window side eith th right id.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try .getProxy().url = "what/ever.php"